# NullReferenceException on bool, int, or other stack variable

Tags: c++-cli, nullreferenceexception

First of all: the title of this post does not match the actual question I have.
But I am also supplying the answer to the original problem (NullRefExcp on bool), so other users will find it's solution here by the chosen title.

I have a class, similar to the following:

```
ref class CTest
{
  bool m_bInit;

  void func()
  {
    if (!m_bInit)
      return;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Today I had the problem that `func` crashed with a NullReferenceException at some point although it had been executed successfully many times before.
The exception occured in the line `if (!m_bInit)`!
I know, you all are saying now, that this is impossible. But it actually was this line. The reason was following:
I have two different variables, both named oTest, but at different places. One of them was initialized: `oTest = gcnew CTest`. Calling `func` on this oTest worked well. The first call of `func` on the other oTest failed with the exception from above. The curious thing is, that the crash seems to happen at the query on `m_bInit`, also the stacktrace of the exception tells so. But this was just the first place where a member of the not initialized object (it was still nullptr) was called.

**Therefore, the advice for other users with the same problem: Check the stack backwards to find a function call on an object that is nullptr/null.**

My question now is:
Why does the execution not fail on the first call of a function of oTest which is nullptr?
Why is the function entered and executed until the first access to a member?

Actually, in my case 3 functions were entered and a couple of variables were created on the stack and on the heap...

Comment: How does that reference c#?

Comment: I am sure I can easily write similar code in C# and cause the same curious behaviour. Therefore, users who are using c# will likely encounter the same problem, which I am giving a solution for here. Furthermore, I think the problem is related to the IL or JIT-compiler, so it's also related to .net.

Comment: Non-static class methods have hidden "this" parameter which is used to access class members. So, when such method is called with null reference, it may fail trying to accessing class member. But generally, this is undefined behavior, it may crash on the call line.

Comment: @AlexFarber: Thanks for the explanation. You could make an answer of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```cpp
 void func()
 {
    if (!m_bInit)
      return;
    ...
 }
```

could actually be written as:

```cpp
void func()
{
    if (!this->m_bInit)
        return;
    ...
}
```

Hopefully now you can see where the problem comes from.

A member function call is just a regular function call that includes the `this` parameter implicitly (it's passed along with the other parameters).

The C++/CLI compiler won't perform a `nullptr` check when calling non-virtual functions - it emits a [`call` MSIL opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx).

This is not actually the case in C#, since the C# compiler will emit the [`callvirt` MSIL opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt.aspx) even for non-virtual functions. This opcode forces the JIT to perform a `null` check on the target instance. The only ways you could get this error in C# is by calling the function via reflection or by generating your own IL that uses the `call` opcode.

Comment: I know that `m_bInit` equals `this->m_bInit`. But I did not know the other details about the compiler. Thank you! (BTW: I will remove the C# tag as I see now that it's not related to C#).